# jQuery UI Resizable affects bootstrap grid columns system

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, resizable, bootstrap-grid

I found a good topic from jsfiddle, and the title is **jQuery UI Resizable affects only on column classes**.  It explains how to change the bootstrap grid system so that it can be resized

Here the original link

> https://codepen.io/delagics/pen/PWxjMN

I try to modify the original code only to migrate it from bootstrap `3.3.7` to `4.0.0` a

Here is my code:

> https://jsfiddle.net/denisc/ty06zwo8/21/

The problem is that the latest version of bootstrap 4 CSS has : `-ms-flex: 0 0 25%; flex: 0 0 25%;` on the grid system, but the old version doesn't have `flex:` it only has `width:`

On my jsfiddle link above, it works, but when I try the code in localhost including all bootstrap compiled CSS and JS bundle, the flex is still showing from `_grid-framework.scss`

I don't want to change anything in the bootstrap code.  Please help me modify the original jQuery code above ^_^ I don't understand any of the whole jQuery code how to make it happen with my case just to migrate it into bootstrap latest version.

```
$(function () {
var resizableEl = $(".resizable").not(":last-child"),
columns = 12,
fullWidth = resizableEl.parent().width(),
columnWidth = fullWidth / columns,
totalCol, // this is filled by start event handler
updateClass = function (el, col) {
el.css("width", ""); // remove width, our class already has it
el.removeClass(function (index, className) {
return (className.match(/(^|\s)col-\S+/g) || []).join(" ");
}).addClass("col-sm-" + col);
};
// jQuery UI Resizable
resizableEl.resizable({
handles: "e",
start: function (event, ui) {
var target = ui.element,
next = target.next(),
targetCol = Math.round(target.width() / columnWidth),
nextCol = Math.round(next.width() / columnWidth);
// set totalColumns globally
totalCol = targetCol + nextCol;
target.resizable("option", "minWidth", columnWidth);
target.resizable("option", "maxWidth", (totalCol - 1) * columnWidth);
},
resize: function (event, ui) {
var target = ui.element,
next = target.next(),
targetColumnCount = Math.round(target.width() / columnWidth),
nextColumnCount = Math.round(next.width() / columnWidth),
targetSet = totalCol - nextColumnCount,
nextSet = totalCol - targetColumnCount;
// Just showing class names inside headings
target.find("h3").text("col-sm-" + targetSet);
next.find("h3").text("col-sm-" + nextSet);
updateClass(target, targetSet);
updateClass(next, nextSet);
}
});
});
```